# Need to be able to navigate the soft keyboard with a remote

Tags: java, android

So I am developing an application that will be used on devices without a touchscreen and will instead be using a remote to navigate the application. I have focus working on the app such that navigation is pretty intuitive. But I have an edit text that lets the user change the name of the device. Problem is that I can't navigate the soft keyboard to enter a name into the edit text. I can't see any way to get the keyboard to have focus so I can then use the remote to enter the new name. Is this possible or will I have to write my own soft keyboard?

Comment: Sorry, can you tell if your `EditText` can't receive focus or the keyboard doesn't open up when you focus the `EditText`?

Comment: The edit text receives focus. But I can't get the remote to navigate the soft keyboard once the it comes up after the Edit Text gets focus